# Recently announced Google Apps Script Dashboard isn't available. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script

Few minutes ago Google [announced](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/three-new-tools-to-help-improve-your.html) a new Google Apps Script Dashboard at https://script.google.com. The announcement includes the following screenshot:

[image: Google Apps Script Dashboard]

I followed the link using my G Suite for Business and consumer (gmail.com) accounts but instead of the Dashboard the Google Apps Script editor is opened. Could be something from my side that avoid that I be able to access the new dashboard?

---

At first I think that the problem could be a staged / scheduled rollout as this is something that Google does. Later I remembered that the cache and cookies stored in my device could prevent to see the latest features among other problems so I tried in incognito mode and this works so I deleted the cache and cookies, restarted my laptop and I was able to see the new dashboard. Then I leave the laptop for a couple of hours and when I tried again the problem occurred again.

---

Following the instructions on the referred announcement I tried to file a bug report but my access is denied, so I made [a post](https://plus.google.com/106510732909452072295/posts/VMKiZXpoQUU) on the Google Apps Script Community on Google+.

---

I found how to create an issue -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71871414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that the issue was fixed

---

As an alternative to access the Google Apps Script Dashboard try https://script.google.com/home

The above works for me